# How to run a jQuery function only for child elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to collapse all child comments including the parent comment when some clicks on the icon nested inside parent comment.

With below jQuery code I was able to get the comments box collapse but now the comments located inside another section are also getting collapsed.

jQuery code -

```
$('.comment-toggle pre').on('click', function(e) {
    $(".single-comment-wrapper .comment-text, .single-comment-wrapper .comment-bottom, .single-comment-outer .child-comment ").slideToggle('fast', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $(".comment-toggle pre").text('[–]');
        } else {
            $(".comment-toggle pre").text('[+]');
        }
    });
});
$('.comment-toggle pre').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.single-comment-wrapper .left-side').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Since HTMLand CSS was too long. I've created a codepen. Below is the direct link to it.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vzrvbm

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your divs makes this tricky, I've been playing around on the fiddle for ~10mins and have come up with this - its heading in the right direction but not perfect...

```
$('.comment-toggle pre').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.single-comment-wrapper').next().slideToggle('fast', function() {
```

All the plus and minuses change because currently your code is targeting classes, it needs to change to be relative to the +/- clicked so $(this). etc

Answer (score 0):

Update you jQuery to search elements relative to your clicked element:

```
$('.comment-toggle pre').on('click', function(e) {

  // find main comment element
  var rootComment = $(this).closest('.single-comment-wrapper');

  // hide child comments of current comment
  var children = rootComment.parent().find('>.child-comment');
  children.slideToggle('fast');

  // hide left part
  rootComment.find('.left-side').slideToggle('fast');

  // hide current comment
  rootComment.find('.comment-text').toggle('fast', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        rootComment.find(".comment-toggle pre", this).text('[–]');
      } else {
          rootComment.find(".comment-toggle pre", this).text('[+]'); 
      }
  });
});
```

Also, if you can change markup to include children elements in the context of the main comment element it would be much more easier to work with. Tree-like view based on `ul` would simplify markup and reduce amount of HTML elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately you code didn't work perfectly. Issues that are still there - 

a) Now when comment is getting collapsed it look like this - http://i.imgur.com/BmL5tOX.png but instead I want it to look like this - https://i.imgur.com/P7mhuYc.png

b) When I'm clicking on second comment - (https://i.imgur.com/E6D7B4E.png) which is parent comment of all the comments below it it's collapsing the comment above it as well.

Comment: Updated answer. Now each comment saves it's state and when collapsed content of the comment hidden too. End you can remove `parent-comment` class.

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should use different classes for divs. Because when you click .content-togle class, javascript code executes actions for all .single-comment-wrapper .comment-text, .single-comment-wrapper .comment-bottom, .single-comment-outer .child-comment classes.